# How to run Keras.model() for prediction inside a tensorflow session?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently having an issue, while executing my model predict of keras inside a tensorflow session.

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    ## want to know how to add model.predict() inside this condition
    predictions = model.predict(#my_model)
    #predictions output is same not appending
```

or any alternative method will be helpful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "issue"? Traceback?

Comment: Keras manages its own internal session and graph (you can get them from the [backend](https://keras.io/backend/) with `get_session()` and `get_session().graph`). In theory it should be possible to run a Keras model in another session for the same graph (e.g. `with tf.Session(graph=K.get_session().graph) as sess`, but you'd need to move over the variable values from one session to another and pick the placeholders and output nodes to call `sess.run` yourself... Is there any reason you not to use Keras internal session?

Comment: @jdehesa No issue of using keras session ... basically I want model.predit() inside a session with while loop to read continuous frames. Like can you help with some sample how we can achieve it?

Comment: Umh, I'm not sure I understand what you need... In principle you should only need to call `model.predict()` as usual, what do you mean "to read continuous frames"? Maybe you can add a bit more of detail about what you are trying to do in the question...

Comment: yes,  "to read continuous frames" means reading videos frames as input to my model.

Comment: Basically i have two models, which i am trying to predict in single while loop.
The first model uses tensorflow session achieved the output its working, but the second model is built on top of keras which as model.predict(#img_pixel) is not predicting new values, the output is same.
But if I am running the second model(ie keras model) outside the session its fine.
I think the below solution will resolve my issue:
need to change the tf.session to keras session (newbie to keras myself)

Answer (score 7):

```
from keras import backend as K

with tf.Graph().as_default():

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        K.set_session(sess)
        model = load_model(model_path)
        preds = model.predict(in_data)
```

Comment: Please add some description to the answer, code-only answers are hyroglyphs to many visitors.

Answer (score 1):

```
from keras.models import load_model
with tf.Session(graph=K.get_session().graph) as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    model = load_model('model.h5')
    predictions = model.predict(input)
```

Above code works for me. I am using keras mobilenet inside tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have to declare placeholder first..then load the model

```
 input_img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, 
                      (1,12,8,3), name = 'image')
 CnnClassifier=tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5',custom_objects 
                                     =None,compile = True) 
 output  = CnnClassifier(input_img)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_intializer())
    output_val = sess.run(output, 
                {input_img:np.expend_dims(img,0)})
```

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaken you could replace

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
```

simply by

```
sess = K.get_session()
```

(K is keras.backend imported)